# Anime/Manga Cons

Tags: conventions

So me and my friends have been wanting to cosplay up and go to an Anime Con. Does anyone know some of the really really fun and popular ones? I know that ComicCon is for comics, and basically everything nerdy including anime stuff, but anything else?

Comment: So are you looking for convention recommendations (recommendations are [off-topic](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site) or looking to find out what the biggest and most popular anime convention are? Are you looking more into viewing anime content or cosplaying? There are a lot of conventions, each with thier own criteria.

Comment: Let's not assume everyone is from the USA. Please be explicit about your location, because I'm entirely sure that we will have different conventions in the Netherlands.

Comment: Uden-its not just USA--I just hear a lot about Comic Con. I don't have enough money to go that far to U.S. anyways. Do YOU have any suggestions about conventions?

Comment: I just assumed that you were from the USA? If you're not, please edit your question and mention in which country/area you live. That way, your question can be answered in the proper fashion - something tailored to your situation. Otherwise we can sit here and tell you all about the big conventions in <Area X>, while that might be useless for you being in <Area Y>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any knowledge of what your whereabouts are your best chance of finding anime conventions would be by checking out lists like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anime_conventions) Do note they do not list all conventions. They only cover the conventions that are broadly known and announced through magazines TV ads and such.

Another source for you to find conventions would be directly asking a shop employee at your local manga/anime reseller. They tend to receive notifications of local events to draw more attention/public to it.